# Word for people older than the speaker in school?

Tags: single-word-requests, ambiguity

I'm looking for a word for what you'd in the workplace call 'seniors', i.e. "My seniors told me where the cafeteria was in Building 1." But in college, 'senior' has a different meaning, and "upperclassmen" doesn't quite work. How should I refer to students in the years above me?

Comment: In Indian schools and colleges, we just refer to them as _seniors_ and _juniors_ if they are in a class above or below ours. As in, _I have a crush on a junior girl of my college_. So, I think it'd be better if you mention your country/region..

Comment: The single-word request  tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: I like the word 'grandee', myself.

Comment: They are your *elders*.

Answer (score 1):

Here in the US, we do not use **seniors** to mean those above you in the workplace.  Generally, if they are higher than you in the organization, they are called **superiors**, although if ranking by time served grants you certain privileges (like who gets laid off last), you may say you have **seniority** **over** (or even you are **senior to**) someone else.  If they are below you, they might be called your **underlings**, or occasionally, **inferiors**.  If they are merely older or younger, or working there longer/less time, there is no specific term for that relationship.

In US high schools and colleges/universities, **junior** and **senior** have specific meanings; respectively, third- and fourth-year students.  First- and second-year students are, respectively, **freshmen** (which is traditionally gender-neutral, but problematic to some, because of the "man" in it) and **sophomores**.

So that leaves the problem of what to use to refer to students in grades above or below yours.  The only solution I can come up to make clear what year you are and then refer to the specific year students you mean:

**As a sophomore, I find the insights provided by the juniors and seniors to be very helpful in making my course selections.**

Of course, if you are a freshman, using **upperclassmen** could mean "everyone else, from sophomores to seniors."  (Many dictionaries say that an upperclassman is either a junior or senior.)

Comment: I was not aware that an [upperclassman](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/upperclassman)  could be a sophomore.

Comment: I see that many dictionaries define upperclassman as only a junior or a senior.  But https://talk.collegeconfidential.com/university-pennsylvania/1186848-what-is-considered-upperclassman-at-penn.html shows that although this definition is common, the definition as "anyone but a freshman" exists as well.  To me, if it's a freshman talking, it probably means "everyone above me."  I've changed the answer somewhat to reflect this.  See also https://www.theodysseyonline.com/difference-freshmen-upperclassmen and http://parents.wfu.edu/my-student-is/upperclassmen/.

Answer (score 0):

In college we don't typically refer to others as senior or junior (in the US at least). The closest we have is upper and lower classmen, but they aren't used often. I'd avoid it, unless you are trying to point out their advanced knowledge (use "Senior", "Junior" or "Sophomore").

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but it might help:
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60815/how-could-i-address-students-in-a-higher-grade-than-me